# Wondering if my reasoning is correct for a tricky calculus limit word problem

Tags: calculus, limits, physics

and thanks for reading my post.  The problem reads like this:

**If a book starts to fall off a building from 120 feet in the air and the position of the book after t seconds is given by s(t) = -16t<sup>2</sup>) + 120.  Find the velocity of the book at t=2 seconds by calculating the limit of the velocity:**

**velocity = lim as x -> 0 of s(2 + x) - s(2) / x**

Since we know that t = 2, we can find the position at that time by plugging in 2 to the equation to get -16(4)+120 = 64.    We plug that into the velocity function where s(2) is:

- s(2 + x) - 56 / x =
- (-16 (2 + x)<sup>2</sup> + 120 - 56 / x =
- -16x<sup>2</sup>-64x-64+64 =
- -16x - 64

So as x goes to 0, the velocity becomes -64 feet per second (downward).  I'm not sure if this is correct but it does seem reasonable.  What confuses me here is the velocity function: the s(2 + x), what is it referring to?  Since s(2) is referring to the position at time = 2, then 2 + x must refer to a position greater than 2, right?  Sort of like the slope equation for a line?

Comment: $s(2+x)$ is the position of the book at time $2+x$.

Comment: And $-64$ is the correct answer.

Comment: $-16(4)+120 \neq 64$

Comment: Oops! I made an error copying it -- it should be 56 as it is later on in the problem.  Thank you for the comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression "Find the velocity of the book at $t=2$ seconds by calculating the limit of the velocity" is very missleading. What you really need to calcuate (and what you indeed *did* calculate) is the *derivative* of the position, which happens to be the velocity.

Say the book is at position $s(t)$ at time $t$, and let $\Delta$ be some time difference. Then the distance that the book travels (well, falls) between time $t$ and time $t+\Delta$ is $$
  s(t + \Delta) - s(t).
$$
The average *speed*, or velocity, of the book between the time $t$ and the time $t+\Delta$ is thus $$
  \frac{s(t+\Delta) - s(t)}{\Delta},
$$
because *velocity* is simply the distance travelled divided by the time it took.

To get the speed as a particular *point in time*, as opposed to the *average speed* within an *interval of time*, you find the limit of that expression as the length of the interval, i.e. $\Delta$, goes to zero. Therefore, the speed or velocity at time $t$ is $$
  v(t) = \lim_{\Delta \to 0} \frac{s(t+\Delta) - s(t)}{\Delta}.
$$

Which, of course, is simply the *derivative* of $s$. Your assessment that this is "something like the slope equation" is therefore spot-on! It's *exactly* the slope equation, but since we're interested in the "slope" at a *particular point*, we have to let $\Delta$ go to zero. Otherwise we'd get the *average slope* over the interval $[t,t+\Delta]$.

In your example, $t=2$, and you correctly computed (I'm writing $\Delta$ instead of $x$) $$\begin{eqnarray}
  \lim_{\Delta \to 0}\frac{s(2+\Delta) - s(2)}{\Delta}
  &=& \lim_{\Delta \to 0}\frac{-16(2+\Delta)^2 + 120 + 16\cdot 2^2 - 120}{\Delta} \\
  &=& \lim_{\Delta \to 0}\frac{-16\cdot 4 \cdot \Delta - 16\Delta^2}{\Delta}
  = -64.
\end{eqnarray}$$
So $s(2+\Delta)$ is the position of the book "shorty after" time $2$ (to be precise, $\Delta$ units after $2$), $s(2)$ is the position at time $2$. The difference is the amount the book travelled within that "very short" interval between times $2$ and $2+\Delta$, and the quotient is hence the average speed within that "very short" interval. The limit as the interval length goes to zero is the speed at time $2$.

Comment: Wow, this is beautifully put.  It made a lot of sense the way you explained it, so thank you very much!  I was confused with the problem's wording, but your explaining it in more calculus-y terms really helped!

Comment: Damn,beat me to it. +1,Great answer.